# Display dialog in fragment android navigation drawer

Tags: android

```
 private void selectItem(int position) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new FaqFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new AboutFragment();
                break;
            case2:
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


            // set title
            alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder
                    .setMessage("Please select your choice")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                            //do whatever you want to do when user clicks ok

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                            // if this button is clicked, just close
                            // the dialog box and do nothing
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
            break;

            default:
                break;

        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(mNavigationDrawerItemTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Above code about I would like to know for one particular `listview` item I need to display dialog with yes or no buttons. but here i getting below line as error and its displaying its not a statement.How can i resolve this,please help me....

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
```

Comment: While keeping cursor on that line it's  displaying  its  not a correct statement and variable alertDialogBuilder its showing cann't resolve symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting error Because of you need to add space between case id like  `case 2:`

For eg:-

```
  case 2:
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);


        // set title
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Alert");

        // set dialog message
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage("Please select your choice")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {

                        //do whatever you want to do when user clicks ok

                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                        // if this button is clicked, just close
                        // the dialog box and do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        // create alert dialog
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // show it
        alertDialog.show();
        break;
```